# Is it possible to make `@SQLDelete` take the `hibernate.default_schema` parameter into account?

Tags: sql, hibernate, annotations

In a webapp, I use Hibernate's `@SQLDelete` annotation in order to "soft-delete" entities (i.e. set a status column to a value that denotes their "deleted" status instead of actually deleting them from the table).

The entity code looks like this :

```
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql="update pizza set status = 2 where id = ?")
public class Pizza { ... }
```

Now, my problem is that the web application doesn't use the owner of the schema to which the tables belong to connect to the DB. E.g. the schema (in Oracle) is called `pizza`, and the db user the webapp uses to connect is `pizza_webapp`. This is for security reasons. The `pizza_webapp` user only has select/update/delete rights, it can't modify the structure of the DB itself. I don't have any choice here, it is a policy that I can't change.

I specify the name of the schema where the tables actually are with the `hibernate-default_schema` parameter in hibernate config :

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">pizza</property>
```

This works fine for everything that goes through mapped entities, Hibernate knows how to add the schema name in front of the table name in the SQL it generates. But not for raw SQL, and the `@SQLDelete` contains raw SQL. This is executed 'as is' and results in a `"table or view not found error"`.

So far we worked around the issue by adding synonyms to the `pizza_webapp` schema, pointing to the `pizza` schema. It works, but it is not fun to maintain across multiple DBs when entities are added.

So, is it possible to make `@SQLDelete` take the `hibernate.default_schema` parameter into account ?

(NB: Obviously I don't want to hard-code the schema name in the SQL either...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any Hibernate solution to this problem. However I found a work-around based on an Oracle feature. I do this in to my session before using it :

```
//set the default schema at DB session level for raw SQL queries (see @SQLDelete)
HibernateUtil.currentSession().doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.createStatement().execute("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA="+HibernateUtil.getDefaultSchema());
    }
});
```

I works fine, but unfortunately only on Oracle (which is fine for us for now at least). Maybe there are different ways to achieve the same thing on other RDBMS as well ?

Edit: the the `getDefaultSchema()` method in my `HibernateUtil` class does this to get the default schema from Hibernate's config :

```
defaultSchema = config.getProperty("hibernate.default_schema");
```

where `config` is my `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

```
@SQLDelete(sql="update {h-schema}pizza set status = 2 where id = ?")
```

Comment: Nice! Do you have a source for this in the doc?